# UINavigationController double sized (in height)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have this code to open a UINavigatonController in an modal screen:

```
NT_WebViewController *privacyPolicyViewController = [[NT_WebViewController alloc] initWithFilePath:filePath];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:privacyPolicyViewController];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

In this situation the Bar shows up to tall and covering parte of the content. Anyone knows why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: You are passing a view like a controller. UINavigationController needs a root view controller, not a root view. I think you should see [this doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) from Apple.

Comment: Thanks Adam.
It is a problem with the names, NT_WebView is actually an UIViewController. I'm going to modify the code for the people to not to confuse. But the problem is still there...